# How to validate a input to numbers only

Tags: php, forms, validation

I'm making a form to allow numbers only. I'm trying to figure out the logic for the input to restrict numbers starting with 1,2,3,4,5.

This is my php code

```
<?php
            $boton=@$_POST['btnParticipar'];
            if (isset($boton)) {
                $nombre=@$_POST['txtNumero'];
                $simbolos=array('<','>','@','?','php','*','[a-zA-Z]');
                foreach ($simbolos as $sim) {
                    $nombre=str_replace($sim,' ',$nombre);
                }
                echo $nombre;
            }
        ?>
```

Comment: Do you want to validate or to replace all invalid chars?

Comment: Instead of sanitizing the input, just check if it `is_numeric($_POST['txtNumero'])` and tell the user when it's not.

Comment: I want to validate, that the user can't pass if they not put a correct number.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy hmm, what you mean? I want that if the user put a number that start with 2 like 2324-5456 don't let them pass until they put a number  that start with 6,7 or 8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it this way aswell. I do not know if it's a good solution, but it should work. The first section in the if-statement checks if the input is an integer, and the second section checks if the first number is 6, 7 or 8.

```
<?php

if(filter_var($_POST['txtNumero'], FILTER_VALIDATE_INT) AND in_array(substr($_POST['txtNumero'], 0, 1), array(6, 7, 8))) {
    echo "Correct";
} else {
    echo "Incorrect";
}

?>
```

Comment: Thanks alot Emil! This is what I was looking for, work perfect.

Comment: Downvoter - please be constructive. I want to know how the solution can be improved. Do you prefer a solution with regex?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest this regex:

```
if(isset($_POST['value']) AND preg_match('/^[6-8]/', $_POST['value'])){
 // do whatever you want
}
```

As i only know from you that the input needs to start with 6,7,8, this may be the best solution.

Comment: Where I add my code? I put it in this way and when I press send the form clean inputs and even I put numbers starting with 6-8.
<?php
    $boton=@$_POST['btnParticipar'];
    if (isset($_POST['value']) AND preg_match('/^[6-8]/', $_POST['value'])){
     $nombre=@$_POST['txtNumero'];
     $simbolos=array('<','>','@','?','php','*','[a-z,A-Z]');
     foreach ($simbolos as $sim) {
      $nombre=str_replace($sim,' ',$nombre);
     }
     echo $nombre;
    }
   ?>